# Previous, Next and Back functionality using angular 8, typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have implemented a custom Previous, Next functionality using angular 8. What this functionality does is, when i click on previous then it shows the results based matching the url routing. As i am getting the data from back end in the below format.

```
    [
  {
    "id": "8a80800e6bd1733c016bd1b2c29b3f73",

    "suggestionId": "tBAKv6Dh",
    "projectId": "8a80800e6bd1733c016bd1b165d63d91",
    "category": "Unsecured",
    "severity": "Major",
    "status": "NEW",
    "issues": [
      {
        "autoSuggestionId": null,
        "issueId": "NiEQOTRlELcsXFbDSQjm",
        "jobId": "8a8080966bda207d016bda614f5d2a48",
        "status": "open",
        "runId": null,
        "jobName": "Dev",
        "envName": "Master"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "8a80800e6bd1733c016bd1b2cb8e4018",

    "suggestionId": "tBAKv6Dh",
    "projectId": "8a80800e6bd1733c016bd1b165d63d91",
    "category": "Unsecured",
    "severity": "Major",
    "status": "NEW",
    "issues": [
      {
        "autoSuggestionId": null,
        "issueId": "NiEQOTRlELcsXFbDSQjm",
        "jobId": "8a8080966bda207d016bda614f5d2a48",
        "status": "open",
        "runId": null,
        "jobName": "Dev",
        "envName": "Master"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "8a80800e6bd1733c016bd1b2cc844024",

    "suggestionId": "tBAKv6Dh",
    "projectId": "8a80800e6bd1733c016bd1b165d63d91",
    "category": "Unsecured",
    "severity": "Major",
    "status": "NEW",
    "issues": [
      {
        "autoSuggestionId": null,
        "issueId": "NiEQOTRlELcsXFbDSQjm",
        "jobId": "8a8080966bda207d016bda614f5d2a48",
        "status": "open",
        "runId": null,
        "jobName": "Dev",
        "envName": "Master"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

For this see the below code:
Template Code

```
<button mat-raised-button class="float-right" (click)="nextVulnerability()">
                  Next<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></button>
              <button mat-raised-button class="float-right" (click)="previousVulnerability()">
                  <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>Previous</button>
<table class="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Risk:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.categoryName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>API Endpoint:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.method}}:{{vulnerabilityDetails?.endPoint}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Auth:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.auth}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Severity:</th>
                  <td>
                    <span *ngIf="vulnerabilityDetails.severity == 'Critical'" class="text-danger"><i
                        class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                      {{vulnerabilityDetails.severity}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="vulnerabilityDetails.severity == 'Major'" class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-warning"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i> {{vulnerabilityDetails.severity}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="vulnerabilityDetails.severity == 'Minor'" class="text-warning"><i
                        class="fa fa-angle-double-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{vulnerabilityDetails.severity}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="vulnerabilityDetails.severity == 'trivial'" class="text-warning"><i
                        class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
                      {{element.severity}}</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Status:</th>
                  <td>
                    <span *ngIf="vulnerabilityDetails.status == 'NEW'" class="text-danger">Open</span>
                    <span *ngIf="vulnerabilityDetails.status == 'CLOSED' || vulnerabilityDetails.status == 'SKIPPED'"
                      class="text-success">Closed</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Vulnerability Description:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.issueDesc}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Suggested Fix Time:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.estimates}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Discovered Date:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.createdDate | timeAgo}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Resource:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.resourceName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Playbook:</th>
                  <td> <a href="javascript:;" [routerLink]="['/app/projects', id, 'template',playbookName]">
                      {{vulnerabilityDetails?.testSuiteName}}
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Scan:</th>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" [routerLink]="[scanHistoryURL]">
                      Recent Scan
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Status Code:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.respStatusCode}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Suggestions:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.suggestion}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Bug Bounty Program Savings:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.bounty | currency:0}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>False Positive:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.falsePositive}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Issue Id:</th>
                  <td>{{vulnerabilityDetails?.issues[0]?.issueId}}</td>
                </tr>


              </tbody>
            </table>
```

The below is the code of ts for handling previous and next functionality

```
nextVulnerability() {
  this.getDetailsByVulId("next")
}

previousVulnerability() {
  this.getDetailsByVulId("prev")
}

getDetailsByVulId(action: string) {

  if(this._clockSubscription != null)
  {
      this._clockSubscription.unsubscribe();

  }


  this.handler.activateLoader();
  this.projectService.getVulDetailsPrevNext(this.id, this.vulnerabilityId, action).subscribe(vulRes => {
      this.handler.hideLoader();
      if (this.handler.handle(vulRes)) {
          return;
      }
      this.vulnerabilityResult = vulRes['data'];
      console.log("this.runNumResult = ", this.vulnerabilityResult);
      this.router.navigate(['/app/projects', this.projectId, 'recommendations', this.id, 'details']);

  }, error => {
      this.handler.hideLoader();
      this.handler.error(error);
  });
}
```

The service written from where i am getting data.

```
getVulDetailsPrevNext(id,autoSuggestionId,action: string){
    return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl + "/" + id + "/auto-suggestion/"+autoSuggestionId + action);
  }
```

Can anyone suggest me what i have done wrong. I am not able to understand. When i click on previous and next buttons then it gives the below errors like "invalid id" from the back end.
[image]

Comment: Please use the `<mat-icon>` element as recommended by Angular Material instead of the previous approach of using an `<i>` element with the `material-icons` class. By default, Angular Material will add the `material-icons` class to the `<mat-icon>` element.